# SLD Layers transparent output from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have two layers in leafletjs. The first layer shows OpenStreetMap and I want a transparent layer above it.

For this layer I have a heatmap and a UK coastline, both vector layers. I am trying to limit the data from the heatmap to just cover the UK.  I have merged these layers in a layer group and using `<VendorOption name="composite">destination-out</VendorOption>` The heatmap data is limited correctly. However the areas outside of the UK are white. Is there a way to transform this to be transparent?

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220378/transparent-nodata-through-wms-in-leaflet?rq=1 answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this is it thanks. It was the png format!